# Android Histogram Equalization

Tags: java, android, image-processing, histogram

I am using the following algorithm in Android Studio to equalize an image.

But it shows error in `getRaster` method and doesnot recognise it. Also `getRGB` is also showing errors.

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

I have edited the code as you said but it crashes.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Object;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



public class webhist extends Activity {

    Bitmap bi = null;


    boolean isColored;

    LinearLayout view;
    LinearLayout view_color;

    boolean flag;

    private int SIZE = 256;
    // Red, Green, Blue
    private int NUMBER_OF_COLOURS = 3;

    public final int RED = 0;
    public final int GREEN = 1;
    public final int BLUE = 2;

    private int[][] colourBins;
    private volatile boolean loaded = false;
    private int maxY;

    private static final int LDPI = 0;
    private static final int MDPI = 1;
    private static final int TVDPI = 2;
    private static final int HDPI = 3;
    private static final int XHDPI = 4;

    float offset = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webhist);


        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        if(metrics.densityDpi==metrics.DENSITY_LOW)
            offset = 0.75f;
        else if(metrics.densityDpi==metrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)
            offset = 1f;
        else if(metrics.densityDpi==metrics.DENSITY_TV)
            offset = 1.33f;
        else if(metrics.densityDpi==metrics.DENSITY_HIGH)
            offset = 1.5f;
        else if(metrics.densityDpi==metrics.DENSITY_XHIGH)
            offset = 2f;

        Log.e("NIRAV",""+offset);

        colourBins = new int[NUMBER_OF_COLOURS][];

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLOURS; i++) {
            colourBins[i] = new int[SIZE];
        }

        loaded = false;

        Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
        upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (flag) {
                    view_color.removeAllViews();
                    view.removeAllViews();
                }
                Intent it = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(it, 101);

                flag = true;

                /*
                 * LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt);
                 * view.addView(new MyHistogram(getApplicationContext()));
                 */
            }
        });

        Button histogram = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hst_btn);
        histogram.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (bi != null) {
                    isColored = false;
                    view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt);
                    view.addView(new MyHistogram(getApplicationContext(), bi));
                }
            }
        });
        Button histogram_color = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hst_color_btn);
        histogram_color.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (bi != null) {
                    isColored = true;
                    view_color = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt_color);
                    view_color.addView(new MyHistogram(getApplicationContext(),
                            bi));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {

            case 101:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    String filename = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
                    bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
                /*
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,10,out);
                bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));*/

                    if(bi!=null)
                    {
                        try {
                            new MyAsync().execute();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        Log.e("TEST", "GetRealPath : " + contentUri);

        try {
            if (contentUri.toString().contains("video")) {
                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } else {
                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    class MyAsync extends AsyncTask
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(0);
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                load(bi);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

            img.setImageBitmap(bi);

            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.hst_btn)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.hst_color_btn)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            dismissDialog(0);
        }

    }

    public void load(Bitmap bi) throws IOException {

        if (bi != null) {
            // Reset all the bins
            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLOURS; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                    colourBins[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {

                    int pixel = bi.getPixel(x, y);

                    colourBins[RED][Color.red(pixel)]++;
                    colourBins[GREEN][Color.green(pixel)]++;
                    colourBins[BLUE][Color.blue(pixel)]++;
                }
            }

            maxY = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLOURS; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                    if (maxY < colourBins[i][j]) {
                        maxY = colourBins[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            loaded = true;
        } else {
            loaded = false;
        }
    }

    class MyHistogram extends View {

        public MyHistogram(Context context, Bitmap bi) {
            super(context);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            if (loaded) {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);

                Log.e("NIRAV", "Height : " + getHeight() + ", Width : "
                        + getWidth());

                int xInterval = (int) ((double) getWidth() / ((double) SIZE + 1));

                for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLOURS; i++) {

                    Paint wallpaint;

                    wallpaint = new Paint();
                    if (isColored) {
                        if (i == RED) {
                            wallpaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                        } else if (i == GREEN) {
                            wallpaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (i == BLUE) {
                            wallpaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        wallpaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }

                    wallpaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

                    Path wallpath = new Path();
                    wallpath.reset();
                    wallpath.moveTo(0, getHeight());
                    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE - 1; j++) {
                        int value = (int) (((double) colourBins[i][j] / (double) maxY) * (getHeight()+100));


                        //if(j==0) {
                        //   wallpath.moveTo(j * xInterval* offset, getHeight() - value);
                        //}
                        // else {
                        wallpath.lineTo(j * xInterval * offset, getHeight() - value);
                        // }
                    }
                    wallpath.lineTo(SIZE * offset, getHeight());
                    canvas.drawPath(wallpath, wallpaint);
                }

            }

        }
    }
public void gray(View view1) {
        operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(bi.getWidth(),
                bi.getHeight(), bi.getConfig());
        histEqualize(bi,operation);
    }


    public int[] CalculateHist(Bitmap bi) {
        int k;
        //array represents the intecity values of the pixels
        int levels[] = new int[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < bi.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bi.getHeight(); j++) {
                int pixel = bi.getPixel(i, j);
                //increase if same pixel appears
                levels[Color.red(pixel)]++;
            }
        }
        //return the histogram array
        return levels;
    }
    public void histEqualize(Bitmap bi, Bitmap bi_out) {
        //call CalculateHist method to get the histogram
        int[] h = CalculateHist(bi);
        //calculate total number of pixel
        int mass = bi.getWidth() * bi.getHeight();
        int k = 0;
        long sum = 0;

        //calculate the scale factor
        float scale = (float) 255.0 / mass;
        //calculte cdf
        for (int x = 0; x < h.length; x++) {
            sum += h[x];
            int value = (int) (scale * sum);
            if (value > 255) {
                value = 255;
            }
            h[x] = value;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bi.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bi.getHeight(); j++) {
                int pixel = bi.getPixel(i, j);
                //set the new value
                k = h[Color.red(pixel)];
                int rgb = Color.rgb(k, k, k);
                bi_out.setPixel(i, j, rgb);
            }
        }
    }
    // int pixel[]; <-- remove this
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        ProgressDialog dataLoadProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dataLoadProgress.setMessage("Loading...");
        dataLoadProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
        dataLoadProgress.setCancelable(false);
        dataLoadProgress.setProgressStyle(android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
        return dataLoadProgress;

    }

}
```

This is My layout.xml file

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lyt"
                android:layout_width="383dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hst_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Show Histogram"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hst_color_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Show Color Histogram"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lyt_color"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="267dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                 />

            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Select Image"
                android:id="@+id/upload"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Equalised image"
                android:onClick="gray"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/upload"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="38dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?  What are you expecting?  (also: you should fix the formatting of your code)

Comment: I am getting an error in the getRaster and get RGB. Also there is an error message for pixel datatype showing expected int[] used int. I have changed it so but then the app crashes. Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: Much better, thanks.  It's also best to paste the error verbatim inside the question.  That avoids ambiguity and also generally includes the exact line of the problem.  Also, there is a `getPixels()` method that returns the entire internal color-array as `int[]` so you can iterate directly.  It's faster, but uses more memory because it makes a copy of the pixels.  You can then create a new bitmap with that array when you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `getRaster()` method in the Android `Bitmap` class. Instead you can call [getPixel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel(int,%20int)) on the `Bitmap` directly. The function returns an integer ARGB value, which you can separate into its various components:

```
int pixel = bi.getPixel(i, j);
//increase if same pixel appears
levels[Color.red(pixel)]++;
```

You can set a pixel like this:

```
 int rgb = Color.rgb(k, k, k);
 bi.setPixel(i, j, rgb);
```

Comment: and what about setRGB!

Comment: i changed as you stated but the pixel datatype used is showing error when I fixed that the app crashes please help

Comment: pixel should be int, not int[]. the getPixel() function does not return an array it's just a single int value

Comment: I added the exact same code you suggested but the app crashes still .earlier it was running fine. Only this class I have added to my code and associated to a button.Look above with the edited code.

Comment: most probably bi is not a mutable bitmap. why are you not using the bitmap you create here? operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), bi.getConfig()); you should pass this bitmap into your histEqualize function along with bi and write to it instead

Comment: Did you mean to say that I shud replace histEqualize(bi) to histEqualize(operation). I am new to this so please consider explaining as a leighman. Thanks
EDIT: When i did this app doesnt crashes but the button press changes nothing.Am I still missing something.

Comment: Change your histEqualizeFunction to public void histEqualize(Bitmap bi, Bitmap bi_out) then change bi.setPixel(i, j, rgb); to bi_out.setPixel(i, j, rgb); call the function like this: histEqualize(bi, operation);

Comment: When i did this app doesnt crash but the button press changes nothing.Am I still missing something.I edited the question code Kindly look at it again as you said.

Comment: you will need to update the UI to show your new bitmap. if you are using an imageview then set call imageView.setImageBitmap(operation) with the new bitmap

Comment: Shall I post the whole code . I think you have taken me to the end and I am just a step back from getting it all run ?
Where to change that coz I think in this method itself we have changed the pixels of output image as bi_out.setPixel(i, j, rgb); Am I right.

Comment: after the call to histEqualize(), add this code: ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img); imageView.setImageBitmap(operation);

Comment: Thankyou very much . You saved someones job man . Thanks again.

Comment: Hey if you are free and as you might have understood the code completely Can I ask you some extension of this code. I am getting a grayscale image  as output I think the reason being I worked upon only the red pixel. Can you suggest me how to equalize all the three colors and get a colored image rather as output.Thanks for your time and dedication,

Comment: Ok My friend I figured it out.

Comment: Hey actually now that you have understood the algorithm , what I intend to next is I was getting previously the Histogram of the image which I import from gallery but now i want that I get the equalised image histogram Hope I have to make just the subtle changes in the code.Please help!

Comment: can you just call CalculateHist(operation); after you have called histEqualize?

Comment: @samgak, i am using the above code but it shows the wrong result.i am giving the blue color image as input it returns the black color image?

Comment: @samgak this is my SO link please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654820/histogram-equalization-is-not-working-in-android?